# Google cloud talent solution quota exceeded error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using google cloud talent solution APIs on free trial account. I am able to execute APIs using API explorer, but for profile read API I am getting error "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'jobs.googleapis.com/profile_read_requests' and limit 'ReadsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'jobs.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxx". I am getting this error on every request. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Just use ... less requests (aka: try again later)?

Comment: I got this error on first request. Can I access profile read API on free trial account?

Comment: AFAIK there is no access to profile_read_requests within the trail.

Comment: You mean,. all profile related activities (create,read,get,delete) are not accessible using free trial account?

Answer (score 0):

The *Profile Search* service is only accessible via the [beta program](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/profile-search/docs) RESTful API and has the limited support either for GCP Cloud Talent [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier) customers or those who're working on billable support plans.